# Injections of Markov Processes

Tags: probability-theory, markov-process

In office hours, a professor mentioned that an injective transformation of a Markov process remains Markov. Intuitively, this makes sense to me as you can "recover" the original Markov process from the new one, but I don't understand how to formalize this.
How can this statement be proved?

Comment: Any reaction to the answer below?

Comment: I think I was hoping for a more formal answer using $\sigma$-algebras. I'll accept your answer in the morning.

Comment: The idea was that a completely formal proof is more or less direct once one knows the answer, and that you were supposed to work it out yourself. Anyway, I fail to understand such a complete lack of reaction.

Comment: This is the only case in which I hadn't accepted or commented on an answer within a reasonable time frame. I think I must have simply forgotten, otherwise I'd have asked for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\bar\mu_0(u)=\mu_0(i^{-1}(u))\qquad\bar P(u,v)=P(i^{-1}(u),i^{-1}(v))$$